# SQL query wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have this query:

```
SELECT `completed`.`ID` AS `ID`,`completed`.`level` AS `level`,`completed`.`completed_in` AS `completed_in`, COUNT(1) AS `right_answers_num` 
FROM `completed` 
INNER JOIN `history` ON `history`.`ID` = `completed`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `questions` ON `questions`.`ID` = `history`.`question`
WHERE `completed`.`student_id` = '1' AND `questions`.`answer` = `history`.`answer`       
GROUP BY `completed`.`ID` 
ORDER BY `completed`.`completed_in` DESC
```

what i need is to get info of each test in completed table (id,level,completed_in,right_answer_num)
the problem with that query is that if there is no one right answer(history.answer = questions.answer) then it doesn't return the row, while it should return the row(id,level,completed_in) and the right_answer_num(counter) should be zero..
please help me,, thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you please provide your data structure and some sample data?

Comment: If `there is no one right answer`, what does your data look like?  No row for that question?  A row for the question, but the `answer` field is `NULL`?  Also, can there ever be more than one row in `questions` for the same question *(such as one question having more than one right answer)*?   As @NWest says, we need to know your schema, constraints, and a complete/categorical description of the data the query is working with.  You may be advised to include example data to better demonstrate your requirements.

Comment: could you define the content of your history table please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    completed.ID AS ID,
    completed.level AS level,
    completed.completed_in AS completed_in, 
    COUNT(questions.answer) AS right_answers_num 
FROM completed
        INNER JOIN history  ON history.ID = completed.ID
        LEFT JOIN questions ON questions.ID = history.question AND questions.answer = history.answer
WHERE 
    completed.student_id = '1'  
GROUP BY 
completed.ID 
ORDER BY completed.completed_in DESC
```

Comment: How is this different from the three answers that came before yours?  It also makes the same assumption as them, so I'll make the same comment...  I doubt that this is enough, but it's impossible to be sure. *MY* inference is that there *IS* a row in `questions` but that the `answer` field is `NULL`. *(As opposed to the row not existing at all.)*

Comment: my is different that I know how left joins work... but your comment is correct on the 2nd part

Comment: Apologies - This has `questions.answer = history.answer` in the `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `WHERE` clause, which at least corrects the mistake present in other answers.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` should be `COUNT(questions.answer)` as the OP says that if there is no answer the result should be `0`.

Comment: thank you so match! now i understood the real meaning of left join.. again, tuns of thanks!!

Comment: is not have problem! Haz a nais dey

Answer (score 1):

use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` intead of an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I doubt that this is enough, but it's impossible to be sure. *MY* inference is that there *IS* a row in `questions` but that the `answer` field is `NULL`. *(As opposed to the row not existing at all.)*

Answer (score 0):

The second inner join is what's causing rows with no record in the questions table to be omitted. An inner join will only return rows that have data in all corresponding tables. Change the second inner join to a left join like so:

```
SELECT 
    completed.ID AS ID,
    completed.level AS level,
    completed.completed_in AS completed_in, 
    COUNT(questions.answer) AS right_answers_num 
FROM completed
INNER JOIN history ON history.ID = completed.ID 
LEFT JOIN questions ON questions.ID = history.question
WHERE completed.student_id = 1       
GROUP BY completed.ID 
ORDER BY completed.completed_in DESC
```

Comment: I doubt that this is enough, but it's impossible to be sure. *MY* inference is that there *IS* a row in `questions` but that the `answer` field is `NULL`. *(As opposed to the row not existing at all.)*

Comment: Oh, and by having `questions.answer = history.answer` in the `WHERE` clause, you've actually un-done the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Dems Ah, nicely caught. This is what happens when you only skim read a query. Also, if the answer in that field is null in the `questions` table is `null` how can that row be associated with the row in the `history` table when that's the foreign key?

Comment: @Dems I guess the OP could be wanting to join on the null value, but this seems unlikely to me. So I gave an answer that I thought would probably solve the problem.

Comment: From the table name, however, I would say that `questions` is the dimension table and includes every question.  If so, a question with no specific answer still has a record, but with the `answer` field set to `NULL`.  It is true, however, that both my perception and your perception are both inferences/assumptions, and that the OP really does need to clarify.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` should be `COUNT(questions.answer)` as the OP says that if there is no answer the result should be `0`.